# Main method won't return

Tags: java

What can be a cause of a java application not exiting ?
The last line of code prints a message and then it does not exit until you press the Stop button.

The code itself does not join any other thread; and the last line of code before the closing curly brace is

```
System.out.println("ok");
```

and it prints "ok", then just halts.

Comment: Show code and tell us how you run it. The information so far is useless.

Comment: The code is pretty complicated, I cannot show it. The thing here is that the code does not call any join method, so the question is: "in general case, what can be the cause" ?

Comment: "The code is pretty complicated". So your problem could literally be anything.

Comment: I think, Eugenes question - from a perspective of a new Java developer - is indeed useful and also could be answered without having the code available.

Comment: Darn, I forgot my crystal ball at home - does someone else have one with him? No? Well then posting a simplified example (though the act of creating one would almost certainly find the error anyhow) or just stepping through the code is the only thing we can't do. I mean we could make a guess that there are non-daemon threads involved, but that's not especially helpful

Comment: @Voo Yes I can share my magic crystal with u)

Comment: Well then you're either creating a thread and not setting its state to daemon (and that not only includes `new Thread` but also Executors and lots of other things,..) and it has not yet finished when main returns or you started a GUI application and didn't specify what should be done when the window is closed (that's basically a special case of #1).

Comment: Thank you all, for answers, indeed there's a hidden part involving Swing, so your answers were very helpful indeed.

Answer (score 11):

Chances are *something* is creating a new non-daemon thread.

If you run in a debugger and "pause" the application, you should see the various threads which are still running.

Basically, the JVM will only terminate when there are no non-daemon threads still around.

Comment: Thank you, Jon, could you provide a code snippet of how to create a non-daemon thread in java so that the main method won't return until that thread runs to completion?

Comment: new Thread(someRunnableWhichRunsEndlessly).start() is one way of doing it, but there are many others (Timer, Executor, etc.)

Comment: For me, it was an ExecutorService. The program exits after calling executorService.shutdown().

Answer (score 5):

A Java application doesn't stop when its main method returns. It exits when `System.exit` is called, or when there is no non-daemon thread running anymore. So if the main method starts a Swing or AWT GUI, and then returns, an event dispatch thread is started , and the application keeps running. Likewise, if it starts a background thread and this thread is not a daemon, the background thread keeps the programm running until System.exit is called.

Answer (score 1):

Non-daemon threads surely are the reason. Even if not explicitly creating one, if you are launching an AWT/Swing GUI, at least the event dispatch thread will be created automatically. In that case, use `System.exit(value)`.

Comment: Oh yes, the Swing is probably the cause. So I think calling System.exit(0) is a safe way?